# Performance difference between Pentium M and Core 2 Duo?

Tags: performance, cpu, intel-core2, intel-pentium

This may be an "apple to oranges" question, but what is the approximate gain in performance of a Core 2 Duo processor over a Pentium M at similar clock speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend:

- [Intel Atom N270 vs VIA Nano vs Core 2 Duo vs Pentium M Benchmarks for Netbook Performance](http://www.eeejournal.com/2009/01/intel-atom-n270-vs-via-nano-vs-core-2.html)
- [Core 2 Duo 1.4 ghz vs. Pentium M 1.73 ghz](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/211516-core-2-duo-1-4-ghz-vs-pentium-m-1-73-ghz.html)
- [Pentium M vs. Core 2 Duo](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/224199-10-pentium-core)